# Get the dynamic value of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tornado

NOTE: I had posted the following as answer to one of the question([Get the value of the dynamic anchor tag and pass it to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747080/get-the-value-of-the-dynamic-anchor-tag-and-pass-it-to-the-next-page)), but there is a glitch. So posting it again. This is not a duplicate of any existing thread

I want to achieve the following using Tornado, html, javascript -

On clicking a link (anchor tag), {which has a dynamically generated value - {{d[0]}} , coming from MySQL database (id).}, I should be able to get the id value (say 100) and send it to the tornado controller and use a logic to pull out all details related to that id.

id -------- Note

100 ----- Note on 100

101 ----- Note on 101

Step 1 -

a href = "TornadoHandlerPath"

would send it as default Get Method, but I wanted it to be sent using Post Method.

So I followed this link - http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

included method post to the form. So my new anchor tag looked like this

```
  a href="javascript: submitForm()" id="id" name="id">
                                   {{d[0]}}  </a>
```

Step 2 - I included a hidden field in html above the anchor tag

```
  <input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid">
```

and In the javascript function I got the value of id and assigned it to the hidden field.

So when the form got submitted, the id would be sent along with the post request.

```
function submitForm() {
var id = $("#id").html();        
var hidden = document.getElementById("cid");
hidden.value = id;
var form = document.getElementById("form"); 
form.submit();

}
```

And in Tornado Handler I caught it with self.get_argument("cid") and move on with the logic implementation.

There is a **glitch** in this method. Even if i click on different id say 103, it still displays the details of id 100 only!! This is because I am pulling the data, based on id. And all rows have same id.

I tried using

```
var id = $(this).closest('td').html(), but it dint work.
```

The entire code is here -

```
$('.alink').on('click', function() {

var id = $(this).closest('td').html();

var hidden = document.getElementById("cid");
hidden.value = id;
var form = document.getElementById("form"); 
form.submit();
});
```

HTML

```
<td>
<form name="form" id="ft" action="/TornadoHandler" method="Post">
<input type="hidden" name="cid" id="cid">                                         
<a href="javascript: submitForm()" class="alink" id="id" name="id"> {{d[0]}} </a>
</form>
</td>
```

I am stuck here for long time. Pls Help Me!!

Comment: What do you mean by *"And all rows have same id"* ?

Comment: For example,both row with id 103 and 104 have same id="id". So when i call 'var id = $("#id").html();', i think it picks the first row and displays the first id which is 100 and displays the details of that id.

    '<a href="javascript: submitForm()" class="alink" id="id"     name="id">103 </a>'

    '<a href="javascript: submitForm()" class="alink" id="id" name="id">'
104 </a>

Comment: id's should be unique within a document, use classnames for multiple things you want to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use data attributes to move data around.no need for the hidden field, just put it straight on the anchor tag

```js
function submitForm(thelink){  alert(thelink.getAttribute('data-info'));
      
}
```

```html
<a href=""onclick="javascript: submitForm(this)" data-info="hello from data attribute 1"class="alink" id="configid" name="configid"> 1 </a>
<a href=""onclick="javascript: submitForm(this)" data-info="hello from data attribute 2"class="alink" id="configid" name="configid"> 2 </a>
<a href=""onclick="javascript: submitForm(this)" data-info="hello from data attribute 3"class="alink" id="configid" name="configid"> 3 </a>
```

Comment: I dunno what the value for data-info is. (Here u have mentioned, "hello from data attribute 1" but in my case I wont know, cos its dynamically generated). When i run the code now, it might be ids 100,103,104. After ten minutes it can be 100,120,125 etc. And when i click 120 it should display all the details about the id 120. I know how to display the details abt 120, but i am not able to say that 120 is being clicked.

Comment: @Newbie it would be the same thing you have in between your `<a></a>`.  So in your case, it's `data-info="{{d[0]}}"`

Comment: but if you don't want to use data attributes, you can change `.getAttribute('data-info')` to `.(textContent||innerText)`

Comment: @Billy , @ Deryck - Thank you soo much!! The id is getting displayed in the alertbox. But on clicking ok, instead of taking me to the next page with the details, its logging me out of the application. Next obstacle!! Will work on that..